# How to run rake task during rails initiation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have my own `secret key` generating script that I've placed in a `rake` command.  I can execute this on its own without starting the `rails server`, but I want to incorporate this `rake` task into the `rails server` initiation so I don't need to call the `rake` task by itself anymore.

Where/How do I run this `rake` command such that it's part of the initiation process?

Comment: Does your rake task have the `environment` dependency?

Answer (score 1):

If the `secret key` rake task doesn't have the `environment` dependency, you can just create a new initializer in `config/initializers` and name it `secret_generate.rb` for example, and in it write:

```
`rake your_task_name`
```

This will run your rake task on rails server initiation.